# how to cancel a a failed domain name registration on aws route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-name

I tried to register a domain name on AWS route 53 and it failed because I didn't have money on the credit card. now I want to cancel the registration. how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to cancel because the registration did not succeed. AWS simply rejects your domain request and let that fail. Just try buying the again.